# Get-mailbox statistics and quota details

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have the below script to get info from all mailboxes with the quota details, but in the `report.csv` file I don't have free space details like you can see in the example below:

```
$results=ForEach($mb in $mailboxes){
    $stats=get-mailboxstatistics $mb
    $props=@{
        alias=$mb.alias
        DisplayName=$mb.displayname
        #StorageLimitStatus=$stats.StorageLimitStatus
        TotalItemSize=$stats.totalitemsize
        #DatabaseName=$stats.databasename
        ProhibitSendQuota=$mb.ProhibitSendQuota
        ProhibitsendReceiveQuota=$mb.ProhibitsendReceiveQuota
        IssueWarningQuota=$mb.IssueWarningQuota
    }
    New-Object PsObject -Property $props
}
$results | Sort-Object TotalItemSize -descending | export-csv c:\script\report.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Output :

```
Alias , Display Name ,TotalItemSize, IssueWarningQuota ,ProhibitsendReceiveQuota , ProhibitSendQuota

User01, User01 ,  46.51 GB (49,935,441,080 bytes) , unlimited , unlimited , unlimited
User02, User02 ,  4.887 GB (5,247,750,394 bytes)   5.86 GB (6,292,127,744 bytes) , 5.95 GB (6,388,764,672 bytes) , 5.91 GB (6,345,815,040 bytes)
```

My desired output is :

```
Alias , Display Name ,TotalItemSize, IssueWarningQuota ,ProhibitsendReceiveQuota , ProhibitSendQuota  , Free Space

User01, User01 ,  46.51 GB (49,935,441,080 bytes) , unlimited , unlimited , unlimited  , unlimited
User02, User02 ,  4.887 GB (5,247,750,394 bytes)   5.86 GB (6,292,127,744 bytes) , 5.95 GB (6,388,764,672 bytes) , 5.91 GB (6,345,815,040 bytes) , 1.023 GB
```

Free space calculation formula is : ( Free Space = ProhibitSendQuota  - TotalItemSize)

If ProhibitSendQuota is unlimited then free space is unlimited.

If ProhibitSendQuota is custom size then free space is Free Space = ProhibitSendQuota  - TotalItemSize.

I also need to get the user account name with the Free Space.

How can I achieve these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
$results = ForEach($mb in $mailboxes){
    $stats=get-mailboxstatistics $mb
    if ($mb.ProhibitSendQuota -eq 'Unlimited') {
        $freespace = 'Unlimited'
    } 
    else {
        $totalBytes = [double]($stats.totalitemsize -replace '.*?\((.*?) bytes.*','$1')
        $prohibitBytes = [double]($mb.ProhibitSendQuota -replace '.*?\((.*?) bytes.*','$1')
        $freespace = [Math]::Round(($prohibitBytes - $totalbytes)/1GB,2)
    }
    $props=@{
        alias=$mb.alias
        DisplayName=$mb.displayname
        #StorageLimitStatus=$stats.StorageLimitStatus
        TotalItemSize=$stats.totalitemsize
        #DatabaseName=$stats.databasename
        ProhibitSendQuota=$mb.ProhibitSendQuota
        ProhibitsendReceiveQuota=$mb.ProhibitsendReceiveQuota
        IssueWarningQuota=$mb.IssueWarningQuota
        FreeSpace=$freespace
    }
    [pscustomobject]$props
}

$results | Sort-Object TotalItemSize -descending | export-csv c:\script\report.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

**Explanation:**

`if` and `else` statements were added to handle conditions of `Unlimited` quota versus a numerical value. `$totalBytes` and `$prohibitBytes` select the bytes value of the `## GB (#,###,###,### Bytes)` format and converts it to type `[double]`. Once those values are number value types, we can perform subtraction. The `/1GB` converts the result to GB. `Round()` method rounds to the nearest hundredths because of the `,2` argument value.

---

It may be worth looking into a more elegant solution using the ByteQuantifiedSize structure. I just found this way to be easier to implement.